# Multiple definitions error in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, linkage

I'm writing a C++ program where each file has it's own set of global variable declarations. Most of these files make use of global variables that were defined in the other files using extern.

Here's an example similar to my program:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Other_File.cpp"

int var1;
int var2;

int main()
{
    var1 = 1;
    var2 = 2;
    otherFunction();
    var4 = 4; // From Other_File.cpp

    std::cout << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3 << " " << var4 << std::endl;

    return(0);
}
```

**Other_File.cpp**

```
extern int var1;
extern int var2;

int var3;
int var4;

void otherFunction()
{
     var3 = var1 + var2;
     var4 = 0;
}
```

When I build this code in Visual Studio (Windows), everything runs fine and the output is correct. But when I attempt to build using g++ on Linux I receive the following error:

> g++ -o Testing Testing.o Other_File.o Other_File.o:(.bss+0x0):
>   multiple definition of `var3' Testing.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
>   Other_File.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of`var4'
>   Testing.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here Other_File.o: In function
>   `otherFunction()': Other_File.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of`
>   otherFunction()' Testing.o:Testing.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined
>   here collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [Testing] Error 1

**Is this because I'm "including" the other file in my main file?**

If not what's the issue with my code?

*Edit: This is the content of my Makefile for g++:*

```
Testing: Testing.o Other_File.o
    g++ -o Testing Testing.o Other_File.o

Testing.o: Testing.cpp
    g++ -c -std=c++0x Testing.cpp

Other_File.o: Other_File.cpp
    g++ -c -std=c++0x Other_File.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o Calculator
```

Comment: By convention one should never include a cpp file in another cpp file.

Comment: What command line are you passing to g++?

Comment: Yes, by including cpp file you end up having definition twice - in the original cpp file and in the file which includes it (I am assuming, you are also compiling the included cpp file independently). **THOU SHANT INCLUDE CPP FILES**.

Comment: I would suspect that you only have Main.cpp in your project in Visual Studio, but you compile both cpp files when building on Linux. So, check what files exactly you compile on Linux. Also see Brian's comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `#include` a source file into another source file. There times and places when that is okay, but only in like less than 0.001% of all programs is that needed.

What you should do is create a *header* file which contains *declarations* of the things needed in both source files.

Then your code would look like this:

1. `main.cpp` source file

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <iostream>
   #include "Other_File.h"  // Note inclusion of header file here

   int var1;
   int var2;

   int main()
   {
       var1 = 1;
       var2 = 2;
       otherFunction();
       var4 = 4; // From Other_File.cpp

       std::cout << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3 << " " << var4 << std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. `other_file.cpp` source file, just like you have it now
3. `other_file.h` header file, a new file

   ```
   #pragma once

   // Declare the variables, so the compiler knows they exist somewhere
   extern int var3;
   extern int var4;

   // Forward declaration of the function prototype
   void otherFunction();
   ```

Both source files would then be compiled separately and *linked* together to form the final executable. This *linking* step is where your build fails. It will notice that the variables defined in `other_source.cpp` are defined in the object file created from that source file, but since you include it into the `main.cpp` source file then the object file created from that source file as well.

This is why you need to learn about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), which is what the compiler actually see. A C++ source file goes through many [phases of translation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), each one doing its own special part. Roughly a *translation unit* is a single source file with all the headers included.

This is also a good reason to learn what the [preprocessor `#include` directive](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) does. It basically inserts the included file, as is, into the source file being preprocessed. Where the `#include` directive was, after preprocessing it will be the contents of the included file, and that is what the compiler will see.

Comment: `other_file.cpp` should not contain `extern int var1; extern int var2;` - they should go in a common header file also (be it `other_file.h` or another)

Comment: Out of curiosity, when would one include a source file (here by source file I mean something which is compiled into it's own object file)

Comment: @SergeyA I've seen it in some low-lever direct-to-hardware simple RTOS code, but then the included source file isn't compiled into an object file that is linked.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, so it is not really a translation unit, just a file which happens to have .c extension?

Comment: Is there a way for me to compile it on Linux the way the program is set up right now? (However inefficient it may be)

Comment: @PaulWarnick The only "Windowsy" thing with the code you show is the `#include "stdafx.h"`. Precompiled headers may be used using GCC, but I've never seen it "in the wild", it's mostly used in Windows and Visual C++. Besides that, I see nothing in the code or the makefile that should not work, out of the box, on just about any system with the right tools.

Answer (score 0):

An include effectively pastes the included file into the including file before the compiler starts working, so what this looks like to the compiler is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
// #include "Other_File.cpp" sub in other file here
extern int var1;
extern int var2;

int var3;
int var4;

void otherFunction()
{
     var3 = var1 + var2;
     var4 = 0;
}


int var1;
int var2;

int main()
{
    var1 = 1;
    var2 = 2;
    otherFunction();
    var4 = 4; // From Other_File.cpp

    std::cout << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3 << " " << var4 << std::endl;

    return(0);
}
```

By itself this isn't a problem. It's funny looking, but it's not a problem. There are no duplicated variables.

```
extern int var1;
```

tells the compiler that somewhere else the there exists `var1`. It will be found and linked later. Carry on. The linker will complain if you lied. In this case, there it is about 10 lines down.

The problem comes when Other_File.cpp is compiled and linked with Main.cpp. The linker finds a full definition of `var3` and `var4` in both Main.o and Other_File.o

You can exclude Other_File.cpp from the build, likely what Visual Studio did for you, and all will be good except for a serious violation of convention: Never include a .cpp file.

Why? Because cpp files, by convention, define stuff and make them real. You can botch a .h file just as badly by defining a variable or function in the header. eg:

```
#ifndef BADHEADER_H_
#define BADHEADER_H_


int fubar; // don't do this
/* do this instead:
extern int fubar;
and place int fubar; into the most logical cpp file
*/


#endif /* BADHEADER_H_ */
```

Everyone who includes badheader.h now has a variable named `fubar` whether they want it or not and when the linker comes along to assemble the program, which `fubar` is the real `fubar`? All of them. Whoops. All the poor linker can do is spit out an error and wait for you to fix the ambiguity.

At the end of the day you can `#include` anything. It won't compile, but you could include a Word doc. You can even perform little tricks like

```
int array[] =
{
#include "filtercoefs.h"
};
```

where array.h is simply

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Useful when you have something like Matlab spitting out filter coefficients, but prefer sticking to the convention to prevent confusion among your fellow coders.

Anyway, C++ lets you do all sorts of stuff. Most of them you better think over a few times before doing them.